# Zorn's lemma - I think I made a counterproof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is from a textbook on topology:

A subset W of the set Z of integers is said to be closed under addition if given any elements w and w′ of W, w+w′∈W.

Prove that there is a maximal subset of Z which is closed under addition and does not contain 9

My problem is as follows: The set of all multiples of 4 does not contain 9 and is closed under addition, the same holds for all multiples of 5. A maximal set must contain both sets, but if that set is closed under addition, we get that 9 is a member of the set.

EDIT: Thanks for the clarification, on the definition I was really lost. Can anyone give me a sketch of a proof?

Comment: The meaning of a *maximal set* $M$ among a collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets is that $M\in\mathcal A$ and $\forall A\in\mathcal A,A\supseteq M\implies A=M$, therefore you cannot conclude that $M$ contains $4\mathbb Z,5\mathbb Z$, etc.

Comment: I'm not well versed in set theory, but what does this have to do with Zorn's lemma?

Comment: The point is that the proof of this statement uses Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Actually I take it back - you can show by hand that all even numbers form a maximal set.

Comment: Isn't Z itself the only maximal set according to this definition ? It's definitely closed and definitely maximal (but does contain 9).

Comment: @hunter: Yes, you don't really need Zorn's lemma in this case. The even numbers (which include the negative numbers as well!) make an easy maximal element. But if you want to prove an analogous statement for $\Bbb R$ then you do need Zorn's lemma.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maximal does not mean maximum.

Maximal set means that you just cannot add more elements while preserving this property, so indeed a maximal set *might* include the multiples of $4$ or the multiples of $5$, but certainly not both as you show.

(Recall that if $(P,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set, a maximal element $p\in P$ is such that whenever $p\leq q$ we have that $p=q$; whereas a maximum is an element $p$ such that for every $q$ we have $q\leq p$.)

Comment: In other words his argument with $4\mathbb{Z}\in\mathcal{A}$ and $5\mathbb{Z}\in\mathcal{A}$ does prove that the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of additively closed sets excluding $9$, cannot have a **maximum** $G\in\mathcal{A}$. But that does not rule out the possibility of **[maximal elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element)** $M\in\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Z incudes multiples of 4 and 5 and is closed ? Do you mean it must be a 'proper' subset of Z ?

Comment: @Tom: We're only interested in sets that $9$ is not their element. Clearly $\Bbb Z$ is out of the question. If you talk about "subsets of $\Bbb Z$" and you talk about "Subsets which have a particular property that $\Bbb Z$ itself does not posses", then yes you talk about proper subsets.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks. I'd probably have worded the question differently "Prove that among subsets not containing 9 there is one that is closed and maximal" (If I understand it correctly). Presumably one maximal set is the even numbers as any odd number added to that set will anable a sum comming to 9.

Comment: @Tom: And that would be very poorly worded, since there is a maximum amongst the sets not including $9$, and it is certainly not closed under addition.